# What does AE community expect from a diamond moderator?

Tags: discussion, election

I want to know the demands of AE community as of today. It can help those who want to nominate themselves as election candidates.

**Existing Diamond Moderators aren't allowed to answer.**

Comment: [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) summarizes it fairly well as a first resource.

Comment: @eldarerathis No, I am interested in AE community as of today. Perhaps, something you failed to do? :)

Comment: Oh, I see; you're looking for feedback from people on what they'd like to see in a candidate. Misinterpreted that.

Comment: Answers to this should be useful for us also -- though I'd hope we'd have been approached about any issues previously.

Answer (score 12):

The only flags that need to be responded to quickly are spam, threats, and those where people have included personally identifiable information. All others can wait until they're gotten too. A Diamond should also have a light touch. An awful lot of things that are flagged shouldn't be.

A Diamond should be fair, firm, and consistent.

A Diamond should have a sense of humor, not take themselves too seriously, and recognize when they're not mentally well-equipped to deal with a situation.

A Diamond should be in constant contact with the other Diamonds. Not necessarily to ensure consensus on every decision (although consensus is important) but so that they all know what's going on and to provide support where needed.

A Diamond should expect to answer fewer questions and to spend a little time on the site every day, several times a day.

Answer (score 3):

I have nominated myself, so I think I should provide an answer.

I believe that a Diamond Moderator should be active, as well as there. They would need to respond quickly to flags - so they can be dealt with.

They would also need to have a good rep - so that people can see that they are trustworthy, as well as having been a member for a good while.

I believe that a diamond moderator should always shed some light on their decisions - I know this is hardly possible, but I believe that they should comment, and help new members follow the site rules, and stay on topic.

I know this has been quick - but this is what I believe.